# Identify a variant of Rummy where hands' size are random

Tags: identify-this-game, rummy

This is a variant of Rummy for 2 or more players, where the size of each player starting hand is random.

- Deck: regular deck with Jokers.
- Deal:

  - The 1st card in the deck determine the number of cards the 1st player receives face down.
  - The next card in the deck determine the number of cards the dealer or player #2 receive.

  - opening:

    - 2-9 are worth a 2-9 cards hand.
    - K,Q,J,T are worth a 10-cards hand.
    - Ace is worth a 21-cards hand.
- Wilds: Jokers and duces are wild.  A wild card can be replaced with the proper card.

What is the name of this game? Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All you've described is the deal.  How does play proceed?  That will significantly impact the game.  The lack of description of play is probably why you are getting closed votes.

Comment: @John I assume that OP expected "variant of Rummy" to be adequate information to describe the play. But it probably is not.